# How to reduce the dimension of a matrix by matrix operation?

Tags: matrix

Given a matrix `mat`, partition it in the following format:

```
SeedRandom[123];
mat = RandomInteger[10, {20, 20}];

mat1 = Take[mat, 10, 10];
mat2 = Take[mat, 10, 11 ;; 13];
mat3 = Take[mat, 10, 14 ;; 20];

mat4 = Take[mat, 11 ;; 16, 10];
mat5 = Take[mat, 11 ;; 16, 11 ;; 13];
mat6 = Take[mat, 11 ;; 16, 14 ;; 20];

mat7 = Take[mat, 17 ;; 20, 10];
mat8 = Take[mat, 17 ;; 20, 11 ;; 13];
mat9 = Take[mat, 17 ;; 20, 14 ;; 20];
```

The original matrix can be rebuilt as follows:

```
ArrayFlatten[{{mat1, mat2, mat3}, {mat4, mat5, mat6}, {mat7, mat8, mat9}}]
```

After performing various calculations over the partitions of `mat`:

```
mat11 = mat1;
mat22 = Total[mat2, {2}];
mat33 = Total[mat3, {2}];

mat44 = Total[mat4];
mat55 = Total[mat5, 2];
mat66 = Total[mat6, 2];

mat77 = Total[mat7];
mat88 = Total[mat8, 2];
mat99 = Total[mat9, 2];
```

I want to build a reduced form of the matrix as:

```
ArrayFlatten[{{mat11, mat22, mat33}, {mat44, mat55, mat66}, {mat77, mat88, mat99}}]
```

It seems that I have problems with the dimensions of the reduced format. Take for example `mat22`, which is the sum of rows in the partitioned matrix `mat2`. It should have a dimension of (10, 1). But it has a dimension of 10 (a list). The same problems appear in other partitions also.

My question is how to format the reduced elements in such a way as to `Append` them consistently.

Put it another way, how to `Append` a (10,1) matrix to a (10, 10) matrix after a row-wise summing of (10,4) matrix.

Comment: "It should have a dimension of (10, 1)" I think you have the wrong expectation of what `Total` does. It's a reducing operator. Just like `Total[{1,2,3}]` returns `6` and not `{6}`. You'll just have to add the desired layers of list back in manually. E.g., `List @ Total[mat, {1}]` and ``List /@ Total[mat, {2}]``

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit: Thanks for your clarification. Isn't there an automatic way to do the manual work? Suppose I have a list of numbers (a vector) and want to represent it as a column matrix. What is the code for this? This will solve my problem.

Comment: Note that MMA does not distinguish between column and row vectors. However, if you want to transform a vector: v into a nx1 matrix: ` v={1,2,3}; List/@v `  results in:  `{{1}, {2}, {3}}`

Comment: @Daniel Huber: Thanks for this tip. I did not know what `List/@v` does.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Sjoerd Smit's comments, I have the following answer to my question:

```
mat11 = mat1;
mat22 = List /@ Total[mat2, {2}];
mat33 = List /@ Total[mat3, {2}];

mat44 = List@Total[mat4, {1}];
mat55 = List /@ Total[mat5, 2];
mat66 = List /@ Total[mat6, 2];

mat77 = List@Total[mat7, {1}];
mat88 = List /@ Total[mat8, 2];
mat99 = List /@ Total[mat9, 2];

ArrayFlatten[{{mat11, mat22, mat33}, {mat44, mat55, mat66}, {mat77, mat88, mat99}}] // MatrixForm
```

generates:

[image]

Although I solve my problem, the answer looks pretty cluttered. I suppose there is a neat way to achieve a better result.